# An Inequality involving integration

Tags: integration, inequality, definite-integrals, pi, integral-inequality

> Show that $$\int_{0}^{\pi} \left|\frac{\sin nx}{x}\right| dx \ge
>  \frac{2}{\pi}\left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} \right)$$

How do I go about proving this inequality ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Make the substitution $u = nx$. Then bound the resulting integral separately on each interval $[(k-1)\pi,k\pi]$.

Comment: Ok, so that substitution will turn it into $\int_{0}^{n\pi} \left| \frac{\sin u}{u} \right| du$ . But I don't get what you mean by "Then bound the resulting integral separately on each interval $[(k−1)π,kπ]$"

Comment: Oh, so do you mean I should do this $\int_{0}^{n\pi} \left| \frac{\sin u}{u} \right| du = \int_{0}^{\pi} \left| \frac{\sin u}{u} \right| du + \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \left| \frac{\sin u}{u} \right| du + .... + \int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi} \left| \frac{\sin u}{u} \right| du$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution :

> Let us substitute $u=nx$.
>
> Then we have , $$\int_{0}^{\pi} \left| \frac{\sin nx}{x} \right| dx =
>  \int_{0}^{n\pi} \left| \frac{\sin u}{u} \right| du$$
>
> Now, splitting up the limits, we get,
>
> $$\int_{0}^{n\pi} \left| \frac{\sin u}{u} \right| du = \int_{0}^{\pi}
>  \left| \frac{\sin u}{u} \right| du + \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \left|
>  \frac{\sin u}{u} \right| du + .... + \int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi} \left|
>  \frac{\sin u}{u} \right| du$$
>
> Now, by the Weighted Mean-Value Theorem for Integrals, we have
>
> $$\int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi} \left| \frac{\sin u}{u} \right| du \ge \min
>  \left|\frac{1}{u}\right| \int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi} \left|\sin u \right|
>  du = 2\ln n\pi \ge \frac{2}{n\pi}$$
>
> Now, adding all inequalities of the following form, 
>   $$\int_{(k-1)\pi}^{k\pi} \left| \frac{\sin u}{u} \right| du \ge
>  \frac{2}{k\pi}$$  such that $1 \le k \le n.$   We get,
>
> $$\int_{0}^{\pi} \left|\frac{\sin nx}{x}\right| dx \ge 
>  \frac{2}{\pi}\left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} \right)$$

Please point out any flaws in the above solution, if you can find one.